# format LT moment with am / pm / h unit depending on locale

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have to handle two locales for en and fr and display formatted hours depending on locale.

I try to do this :

```
  const hour = moment({
    hour: 15
  }).format('LT');
```

It display 15:00 for fr and 3:00pm for en . I want 15h for fr format and 3 pm for en.

I tried to use the updateLocale method to add specific options, with LT format, but I can't arrive at the result.

```
    const optionsFR = {
      longDateFormat: {
        LT: 'HH:mm',
      },
      meridiem: (): string => 'h',
    }
    
    const optionsEn = {
      longDateFormat: {
        LT: 'h:mm a',
      },
      meridiem: (): string => 'h',
    }

moment.updateLocale(locale, options);
```

I could modify the LT option to do `LT: h a` for en and `LT: HH` for fr. but I can't display 'h' unit for fr-fr. Do I have to do it manually?

Comment: en-gb and fr-fr are languages, not locales. ;-)

Comment: You're right, so en and fr are locales :)

Comment: Nope. The part before the hyphen, e.g. "en", is language tag. The part after the hyphen, e.g. "-en" is a sub–tag. The use of the term "locale" to describe a language tag is a misnomer propagated by the ECMA 402 Internationalisation Specification. See [IETF language tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the *h* for the french locale using `LT: 'HH[h]'` in [`longDateFormat`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/).

As the **Escaping characters** section of the docs states:

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

Example:

```js
const optionsFR = {
  longDateFormat: {
    LT: 'HH[h]',
  }
}

const optionsEn = {
  longDateFormat: {
    LT: 'h a',
  }
}

moment.updateLocale("en", optionsEn);
moment.updateLocale("fr", optionsFR);
const hour = moment({
  hour: 15
});
console.log(hour.locale('fr').format('LT'));
console.log(hour.locale('en').format('LT'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```